# Manage codable in didset Property observer ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct, codable, decodable

I want to manage custom codable array using didset properties to set different dataTypes. Here ReportSortModal is

```
struct ReportSortModal<T:Decodable> {
    var title : String?
    var data : T?
}
```

Whereas `Fieldreport` & `DustbinInspection` are two different codable structures.

The error & code is below:

[image]

Comment: returning in didset ?

Comment: no willset will come. But I do want to change the datatype of arrFieldReport according to my conditions